# How to make a loop range in queryset when fetching data from database?

Tags: python, html, django

I am working in `views.py` to fetch data from database. All the items are present in database. I am trying to make a loop within range of 2. Because I arranged items in 3 columns in `index.html`. But when I looped the items in range 2 it is displaying all the items in one column. How to resolve this issue?

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('srh')
    if query:
        target1 = Destination.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

        target1 = Destination.objects.all()
        for field in target1:
            [Destination(img = f'{field.img}',
             title = f'{field.title}') for __ in range(2)]

        context = {'target1': target1}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)

        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html')
```

*index.html*

```
<div>
  {% for dest1 in target1 %}
   {% if dest1 %}
     <div>
       <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}">
         <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}" alt="" />
           <h3>{{dest1.title}}</h3>
        </a>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
   {%endfor%}
  </div>
```

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: Please could you add the template to reproduce a simple example ? and why `target1` is declared twice ?

Comment: ```target1``` two times because I am using ```search bar``` when I write something in it. That is why first ```target1``` is for search bar.

Comment: but the second will override the first

Comment: I have added index.html

Comment: `target2` is missing in the code you paste here

Comment: I have removed ```target2```. Could you please give the solution? The problem is in ```views.py```

Answer (score 1):

This whole approach, as you have repeatedly been told, is nonsensical.  `target1` is already a queryset of Destination instances. There is **absolutely no point** in that  for loop and list comprehension which only create new Destination instances from the ones you already have. Especially as you don't even assign the result of that comprehension to a variable anyway, so it's immediately thrown away.

So stop doing this, and just get the instances and pass them to the template:

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('srh')
    if query:
        target1 = Destination.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    else:
        target1 = Destination.objects.all()

    context = {'target1': target1}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Now, if you want columns in your template, you will need to do something to actually create those columns. Nothing in your current code does that; you just have a div. But if you wanted to use Bootstrap CSS for example, you could do something like:

```
<div class="container">
  {% for dest in target1 %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
       <div class="col-4">{{ dest1.title }}</div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}</div>{% endif %}
  {% endfor %>
</table>
```